# pandas create new group by columns based on other categorical columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assuming I have a dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"doctor id": ["1", "1", "1", "1"],
                   "patient id": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                   "drug name": ["a", "b", "b", "b"]})
```

How can i create 2 new columns based on the "drug name" categorical columns (drug_a_count & drug_b_count) and calculate how many drug each doctor prescribe to his/her patients?

Ideal output

```
  doctor id drug_a_count  drug_b_count
0         1          1         3
```

So far I can only get to this:

```
df.groupby(['doctor id','drug name'])["doctor id"].count().reset_index(name="count")
```

The incorrect output

```
doctor id   drug name   count
0   1   a   1
1   1   b   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [`groupby.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html) then unstack and rename the column names

```py
out = (df.groupby('doctor id')['drug name'].value_counts()
       .unstack(-1)
       .rename(columns=lambda col: f'drug_{col}_count')
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

  doctor id  drug_a_count  drug_b_count
0         1             1             3
```